# sdf_persist taking a very long time on sparklyr

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, sparklyr

I have a very large table stored on our SQL Server that I'm trying to run some operations on. The table is stored as a clustered column-store index and is ~0.23 TB in size. No one is able to work with it in SQL Server so I'm trying to see if I can work with it through our spark cluster with 4 nodes, 32 CPUs, and 40G of RAM on Yarn.

I'm getting very long run-times (~1 day) when I try to cache the results of a very simple query. but I'm not seeing my resources fully utilized. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or meta suggestions on what I'll need to do to achieve better run times?

My code thusfar:

```r
config <- spark_config()
config$spark.driver.memory <- "4G"
config$spark.executor.memory <- "4G"
config$spark.executor.cores <- 2
config$spark.executor.instances <- 9
# this is a wrapper for spark_connect that connects to the yarn cluster
sc <- bigly_connect(config)
# this results in 7(?) yarn containers with total memory usage of 31G

# this is a simple wrapper for spark_read_jdbc
# note Im partitioning the read into 280 pieces
full <- spark_read_sql(
  sc,
  "<table>",
  "<db>",
  "<server>",
  "<user>",
  "<pass>",
  memory = F,
  options = list(
    lowerBound = "20150101",
    upperBound = "20180801",
    numPartitions = "280",
    partitionColumn = "date"
  )
)

parts <- full %>% 
  distinct(prem_id) 

# Ive specified kryo serializer in bigly_connect()
sdf_persist(parts, storage.level = "MEMORY_ONLY_SER")
```

While this is processing I'm typically seeing CPU, Memory, and Storage usage percentages between 0-18%. What's going on? How can I re-think my analysis to achieve better run-times?

Thanks in advance for reading this and helping me :)

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of persist here?

Comment: definitely, I wanted to serialize to memory because I'd use this RDD for other things, but I wasn't sure if `sdf_cache` serialized it so I just used this instead. Sidenote- I was facing similar runtimes with `sdf_cache`

Comment: One note - Kryo serializer is not used here. Additionally "No one is able to work with it in SQL Server" is already a warning sign. 250GB is not that large to cause serious database problems, and since the same database has to provide data to you Spark app... Also, 200 partitions for ~250GB of data seems to be way to low. I'd consider increasing around ~4 fold or more. Finally computing distinct values would be a better thing to do in the query, on the Spark side. So for now I suspect that the bottleneck might the database.

Comment: If not, you can try to dump data first and read it from disk. If not [Azure/azure-sqldb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) claims to be more efficient than built-in Spark tools.

Comment: These comments are truly priceless. I'll increase the number of partition first, but what could be wrong with the db? Would it be the indexing scheme? It's stored as a clustered columnstore index which I'm new to but our SQL guy likes.

Comment: Most of the columns are type `varchar` but date and another column are numeric.

Comment: I am not a DBA, and don't use SQL server so I can only guess. For example 0.25 GB is not incredibly large, but it is large enough to cause problems if all records you try to load reside on the same physical device. And having ~120 concurrent readers  can throttle system even more. If I were to analyze the problem I'd try to check runtime system statistics  and see what they tell me (high load, high wait, something else?).

Comment: Would this be runtime stats on the SQL Server or in Spark? If in Spark how does one access this data? I'm running with the ~4k partitions you mentioned and it is still very slow.

Comment: I would start with SQL server, and if you cannot determine problem there, move to Spark, but looking at the code you have right now, the only issue I can imagine, is `distinct` call, which will require full shuffle.